# C Preprocessor getting rid of the __align__ and __attribute__

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, c-preprocessor

I am working with a primitive **C** Parser that does not handle the Preprocessor directive.

I can preprocess most of the header with the -E switch without problem.

Lately I found cases when **attribute** and **align** are present.

I tried to get rid of them with this tweak:

```
gcc -D "aligned(ARGS)" \
    -D "__align__(ARGS)" \
    -D "__attribute__(ARGS)" \
    -E /usr/local/include/fancyheader.h
```

**Update:**

But without success, example:

```
struct __attribute__((aligned(16))) long4
{
  long int x, y, z, w;
};
```

The above statements is transformed to, with that "1" pending around

```
struct 1 long4
{
  long int x, y, z, w;
};
```

**Who knowzs the correct way to get rid of the __align__ and __attribute__ extensions ?**

Comment: Okay, what is this primitive C parser, and what are you trying to do with it?  What happened when you tried to get rid of those things with the -D directive?  Just "without success" tells us nothing.

Comment: What happens if you specify `gcc -x c -D ....` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What happens when you use `-D "aligned(ARGS)="` ?

Comment: That works for me. Except you need to remove that quotation mark.

Comment: By default (if there's no `=`), the -D option defines the macro as expanding to `1`

Comment: @Chris cool, do you remember where you read that?, I don't recall to have ever seen it

Comment: @TonyK: i added a closing quotation mark to guard against shell interpretation of the parentheses.

Comment: @fabrizio: should be in the documentation of your C compiler.  Gcc lists it with all the other preprocessor options.

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor assigns the value `1` to all macros defined on the command line without specifying a replacement list. For instance, if you compile with -DFOO:

```
std::cout << FOO << std::endl;
```

will print `1`. If you want to explicitly set the macro replacement list to be empty use `-DFOO=` (or in your case `-D__align__(x)=`.

Answer (score 0):

How about un-defining all built-in and pre-defined macros with the `-U` option, and then creating new definitions with the `-D` option?

Comment: I get this error: <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers